# VBA Logic issue with If statement

Tags: vba, excel

I need some help with a logic statement I can't seem to fix.

```
If (SheetExists("Sheet1") = False Or SheetExists("Sheet2") = False Or SheetExists("Sheet3") = False) Then 

MsgBox ("A Key Sheet does not exist:" & vbNewLine & "Sheet1 Exists: " & SheetExists("Sheet1") & vbNewLine & "Sheet2 Exists: " & SheetExists("Sheet2") & vbNewLine & "Sheet3" & SheetExists("Sheet3"))

Else

Exit Sub

End If
```

The test case I am using should have each `SheetExists` statement return true and therefore not msg the user. However, the `Then` statement always runs even when it shouldn't. It will print that each criteria was True, but still run the `Then` statement

*What I want:
If any sheet does not exist-> tell me which sheets exist.
Else-> do nothing*

*Error:
when all sheets exist: it still msgs the user*

I know that SheetExists works because I wrote another sub to test it and it works fine.

Sheet Exists code:

```
Function SheetExists(sheetName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
Dim sht As Worksheet

If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
On Error Resume Next
Set sht = wb.Sheets(sheetName)
On Error GoTo 0
SheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Show your SheetExists function. There may be a problem with that.  the code above works fine for me.

Comment: Can you post the code for SheetExists?  My first thought would be that it's not returning a Boolean.  We can't test this without that code.

Comment: With your code I still get exactly what is expected.  When the three sheets exist then nothing happens.  If one or more is missing then I get the message box.  So either there is more to your code, or you have a typo in your actual code.  Double check the names of the three sheets in the if statement and make sure they are spelled correctly.

Comment: Can you Remove your "on error"  lines to Test if no errors occure? Maybe you are surpressing an error message which you need to solve your problem. Have you tried debugging?

Comment: @etalon11 in this kind of procedure, the `On Error` lines are actually required, because it's relying on error trapping for deciding if the sheet actually exists. Error = no sheet, no error = sheet.

Comment: That optional second argument is for you to pass in a workbook reference *if the workbook you're checking for the sheet isn't the same as the one where your code is running*.  If you're checking a different workbook then you need to include that argument when you call the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IF statement works just fine for me, assuming the `SheetExists` code is this:

```
Function SheetExists(ByVal sName As String) As Boolean

    SheetExists = Evaluate("ISREF('" & sName & "'!A1)")

End Function
```

Comment: @JeffManville Code works just fine for me with your `SheetExists` code as well.  It only fires the `MsgBox` if one of the provided sheetnames doesn't exist.  Are you absolutely certain that sheets "Sheet1", "Sheet2", and "Sheet3" exist and they are named exactly that with no leading or trailing spaces?

Comment: @JeffManville I also see that your `SheetExists` code has an argument for a workbook.  I would double check that the sheets exist in that workbook and are named exactly what you're looking for with no leading or trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here:

```
If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
```

`ThisWorkbook` and `ActiveWorkbook` can be very different things.

- `ThisWorbook` refers to the workbook in which the currently executing code resides. In this case, whichever workbook the `SheetExists()` function is running from.
- `ActiveWorkbook` refers to the workbook that is currently active in the user's application window.

---

Try changing that line to:

```
If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
```